# Bootstrap Navbar drop down menu in the wrong place

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The issue is with the icon bars that can only be seen when on a small or extra small screen. When you click the icon bars you are supposed to have a drop down menu show up by the icon bars, instead it shows up right next to the title. I cannot figure out the issue. Here is my code:

HTML

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Art and other cool stuff</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Swag</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">WillyWonka</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Masterful</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try adding a pull-right class to the div wrapped around your unordered list like this:

    <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse pull-right">

Is that the effect you're looking for?

Comment: The dropdown should take up a width the size of the screen and the item names should appear on the left side. Try using `float` to change that. Provide a link to a jsfiddle or images of what you're getting vs. what you expect to get a more precise answer.

Comment: Thank you, his actually steered me in the right direction and fixed my issue. Thanks :)

Comment: Why is there a CSS tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add .navbar-header div.So its happens like this.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/swaranan/b651eprs/)

code:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Art and other cool stuff</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Swag</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">WillyWonka</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Masterful</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```